# Connecting to Sharepoint File System using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

Can someone help explain why when trying to save or copy files over to a file structure that is part of a SharePoint site the code only seems to work if I use the SaveAs code once everytime I log on to my network

The code also works on other excel spreadsheets

```
 If Dir("//teamspace.healthcare.siemens.com/content/90002613/Documents/" & Filename & "", vbDirectory) = "" Then

       MkDir ("//teamspace.healthcare.siemens.com/content/90002613/Documents/" & Filename & "")

       Else
```

The code I need to run once on logon is

```
With ActiveWorkbook

            Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="https://teamspace.healthcare.siemens.com/content/90002613/Documents/Budget_Presentations/SavedFileName.xlsm"
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

           End With
```

I have tried multiple things, like using different directories, turning the slashes round, using variables. Nothing seems to work, even though exact same code has worked multiple times on a different spreadsheet

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to save it as a macro enabled workbook, then you need to explicitly tell the SaveAs command that. Like this:

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="https://teamspace.healthcare.siemens.com/content/90002613/Documents/Budget_Presentations/SavedFileName.xlsm", XlFileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Comment: Hi brax,

Maybe my explanation is great. I don't actually want to save the excel file, its just the other code wont connect to the sharepoint site unless I include that code. I am trying to check if there is a directory already there and then copy a file over to it, the copy file code and directory check code work fine on my local, but as soon as I try to connect it to sharepoint it wont work. Unless I save a random file to the sharepoint first, then it seems to make the connection, until I log off and log back on, then I have to run the save file code again to be able to copy files over